# Using regex with Java's TreeSet or Collections.BinarySearch

Tags: java, regex, search, optimization, tree

I'm trying to create a matching program that, when given some regex for a word say "C[A-Z]T", find all words that will match that regex from a List of words. Matches for my example would be CAT, CUT, COT.

My goal is to make this as fast as possible for very large lists of words. I've tried implementing using Java's TreeSet, but the search takes extremely long because I have to iterate over every word in the Tree. Even when I randomize the list before putting it into the tree, the search is much too slow.

So my question is, can I use the internal Contains(), or is there some other data structure that Java provides, that can work with regex? Thanks..

I'm thinking of using an AVL or Red-Black "hashmap" (but not really), with lengths as keys and words as values. That would mean I need to allow for multiple keys that are the same, but with each key mapping to a different value. So my get would return a List of values, not a single value. Is there somewhere I can find an implementation of such a data structure? Or at least a base to get me started.. I'd really rather not roll my own.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class WordSearch {
    SortedSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public WordSearch(List<String> allWords) {
        // long seed = System.nanoTime();
        // Collections.shuffle(allWords, new Random(seed)); // randomize
        tree.addAll(allWords);
    }

    public List<String> solutions(String pattern, int max) {
        pattern = pattern.toLowerCase().toUpperCase();
        pattern = pattern.replace("*", "[A-Z]");
        Pattern find = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<String> it = tree.iterator();
        while (count < max) {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String word = it.next().toLowerCase().toUpperCase();
                Matcher match = find.matcher(word);
                if (match.matches()) {
                    result.add(word);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your regex/Pattern before hand, you could build up something like a bloom filter, but that's really not all that different from building up `Collections` like `matchesPattern0`, `matchesPattern1`, etc., and that's basically how a database's index works.  You might also just want a prefix tree.

In your case, the only way a data structure would help is if the regex is anchored, i.e. a first or last character or character range is specified. Otherwise, you'll have to go over the entire data structure, anyway. Basically, the `^C[A-Z]T$` case is *so* specific that no one went out and build an optimized data structure for this.

Id you're feeling clever and desperately need this, you're best bet is a method that converts a `Pattern` to a "min" and "max," so `CAT` and `D`, then use `SortedSet.subSet`, and apply a filter to the results.  But really, this optimization rarely works.